# Make asynchronous web service call as synchronous in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, asynchronous, synchronous

I am beginner in web service development.
We are building REST web application in java using Spring 3.

Web service which we are consuming has an asynchronous login method. We have provided them a call back listener URL where their service postback the response.

So when we send a request for login we receive a blank response as an acknowledgment. And service send a response with actual data on the listener URL.

Please help, how should i design/implement to call login service as synchronous call?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Below is the listener/controller of postback message which extract the token and set into a object.

```
@Controller
public class PostbackController {

    @Autowried
    public LoginResponse loginRS;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/callbacklistener", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String postbackHandler(@RequestParam("postback") String requestMessage) {
        //We extract the token value from requestMessage.
        String token = requestMessage;
        loginRS.setToken(token);
        return "<Confirm/>";
    }
}
```

Below is a thread which call the login service and wait for 10 sec. Every 2 sec it checks for that status of object.

```
public class LoginService extends Thread {

    @Autowried
    public LoginResponse loginRS;

    public LoginService() {
        this.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread Start.");
            this.login();
            System.out.println("Thread Complete.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    public LoginResponse login() {
        String loginXML = "";
        String response = "";//by calling REST web service using RESTtemplate we get blank response.

        for(i=0; i < 6; i++) {
            if(loginRS.getToken().length > 0))  {
                //Got the response exit from thread
                break;
            }
            else {
                //Wait for 2 second
                Thread.sleep(2000)
            }
        }
        return loginRS;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks

Comment: Oh “lovely”. While I don't know if that violates the “rule” of REST directly, it surely violates the spirit of the principles. (It also requires that the client host a web service somewhere, which is just nasty.)

Answer (score 1):

Some Pseudo code to give you the idea

```
Login request sender Thread{

    acknowledgement = sendLoginRequest

    sleep() or wait on some lock

}


ListenerThread{

    response received = listenForResponse

    lock.notifyAll() or interrupt Login Thread

}
```

Doing this makes this synchronous.

**UPDATE:**

```
public class PostbackController {

        @Autowried
        public LoginResponse loginRS;
        //instance 1 injected by Spring where you set the token
}



public class LoginService extends Thread {

    @Autowried
    public LoginResponse loginRS;

    //a NEW instance will be created here also by Spring which will not have that token you set, as this is a new instance. So Thread will keep sleeping always.
}
```

Make `PostbackController` nested class of `LoginService` and use the same instance of `PostbackController`

Comment: Thanks !! Yes that could be the possible solution and we already looking into this. But it isn't working as expected. We have created a controller which works as listener. When listener receives postback message it update an object. There is a service which call the login service as thread and wait for 10 sec and every 2 sec it checks for the status of an object.

Comment: Yes this method is called `polling`, but the disadvantage is when there will be many threads it will create overhead. So you should rather use interrupt() or notify() mechanism to wake the sleeping thread. That would be more efficient. And if you could share new code I may help you with this.

Comment: When we `@Autowired` an object it doesn't create any new instance but it share same object. Also, here `PostbackController` is controller so i didn't get idea of nested class.

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani didn't know that :) not a Spring developer. Is `token` that is updated by `setToken()` declared `volatile` ? Cz if `@Autowired` shares the instance then that is what might be creating the problem. Check it out

Comment: I am using the Apache GenericObejctPool to maintain the session pool. So the lifecycle of the pool object is completely handled by the Apache Pool library.

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani could you please do `System.out.println(loginRS)` at both places where you are setting and getting the `token`. Just to make sure these are same instances for safe side.